# How to use regular expression to retrieve the specific string in different OS file Path

Tags: regex

How to use regular expression in javascript to retrieve the datatime stamp path in different OS

Here's the example.

D:\\deploy\\logs\\uat\\20140929101121\\build1.log

//usr//bin//app1//log//dev//20140929100730//build2.log

//usr//bin//app1//log//dev//20140929100728//build1.log

And I would like to retrieve the string of

20140929101121

20140929100730

20140929100728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\d+)(?=[\\\/]{2}[^\\\/]*$)
```

You can try this.This will remove the dependency of having `14` digits.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5nP7/1

Answer (score 0):

In the example data you provided it would be fair to say that you want 14 digits that will be followed by a path separator of either `//` or `\\`.

If that is the case then it is as simple as:

```
(\d{14})(?=[\\/]{2})
```

This will capture the 14 digit timestamp, where it is followed by either // or \

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this i used in perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = qq(D:\\deploy\\logs\\uat\\20140929101121\\build1.log

//usr//bin//app1//log//dev//20140929100730//build2.log

//usr//bin//app1//log//dev//20140929100728//build1.log);

$string =~ s{^(?:.*?)(?:[\\/]*)([0-9]{14})(?:[\\/]*)(?:.*?)$}{$1}igm;

print $string;
```

The Output:

```
20140929101121

20140929100730

20140929100728
```